# How to access elements in an array in reverse order?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, decrement

So I don't understand what I am doing wrong(Syntax error, Nested loop, or just silly mistake??). My compiler ask me to Press any key to continue . . . Could you point me in the right direction??

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    const int MAX_ROWS = 2;
    const int MAX_COLS = 4;

    int BigSmall[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = 
    {
        {1,3,5,7},
        {2,4,6,8}
    };

    for( int Row = 2; Row > MAX_ROWS; Row--)
    {
        for( int Column = 4; Column > MAX_COLS; Column--)
        {
            cout << "Integer[" << Row << "][" << Column << "] = " << BigSmall[Row][Column] << endl;
        }   
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is the compiler which has a problem; I guess it is the execution. In a for loop the test is executed at the beginning of the loop: from the beginning, `Row` does not verify `Row>MAX_ROWS`, so the outer loop is never executed.

Comment: What you want, from the title "reverse order", is something like `for (int Row=MAX_ROWS; Row-->0; )`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for( int Row = 2; Row > MAX_ROWS; Row--)
```

`Row` and `MAX_ROWS` both equal 2 what you want is `Row > 0`

Same goes for the column loop

Answer (score 1):

> Syntax error, Nested loop, or just silly mistake?

The later: you start your inner loop at four, and continue while `Column` is *above* four. This is the same as never starting it. The outer loop has the same issue.

You should start your loop at `SIZE-1` (i.e. `MAX_ROWS - 1` or `MAX_COLS - 1`) and continue while you are above or at zero:

```
for( int Row = MAX_ROWS-1; Row >= 0 ; Row--) {
    for( int Column = MAX_COLS - 1; Column >= 0 ; Column--) {
        cout << "Integer[" << Row << "][" << Column << "] = " << BigSmall[Row][Column] << endl;
    }   
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Pe1s0H)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
for( int Row = MAX_ROWS - 1; Row >=0 ; Row--)
{
    for( int Column = MAX_COLS - 1; Column >= 0 ; Column--)
    {
        cout << "Integer[" << Row << "][" << Column << "] = " << BigSmall[Row][Column] << endl;
    }   
}
```

?

Comment: hmm.. okay it works now. Would you explaining why that works??

Comment: Well, it just does what is written. E.g. for rows, you have `MAX_ROWS` (2) of them with numbers 0 and 1 (as we start count from 0). To look over them in reverse order we start from `MAX_ROWS-1` (that is 1) and finish at 0 decrementing the loop counter.